# Removed contours aren't gone

Tags: opencv, contour

I am trying to remove any contours that aren't in a square like shape. I check the image before and after to see if any contours have been removed. I use the circularity formula and values between 0.7 and 0.8 are square shaped. I expect to see that some contour lines are removed but none are

Here is what I have done so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat capturedFrame = Imgcodecs.imread("first.png");

        //Gray
        Mat gray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(capturedFrame, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        //Blur
        Mat blur = new Mat();
        Imgproc.blur(gray, blur, new Size(3,3));
        //Canny image
        Mat canny = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(blur, canny, 20, 40, 3, true);


        Imgcodecs.imwrite("test.png", canny);

        //Dilate image to increase size of lines
        Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(1, new Size(3,3));
        Mat dilated = new Mat();
        Imgproc.dilate(canny,dilated, kernel);


        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        //find contours
        Imgproc.findContours(dilated, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        //convert image 
        Imgproc.cvtColor(capturedFrame, capturedFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);


        //Draw contours on original image
        for(int n = 0; n < contours.size(); n++){
            Imgproc.drawContours(capturedFrame, contours, n, new Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 1);
        }

        Imgcodecs.imwrite("before.png", capturedFrame);

        //display image with all contours
        Imshow showImg = new Imshow("displayImage");
        showImg.show(capturedFrame);


        //Remove contours that aren't close to a square shape.
        for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){

            double area = Imgproc.contourArea( contours.get(i)); 
            MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());
            double perimeter = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true);

            //Found squareness equation on wiki... 
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_(image_analysis_and_microscopy)
            double squareness = 4 * Math.PI * area / Math.pow(perimeter, 2);

            System.out.println("Squareness: " + squareness);


            if(squareness <= 0.7 && squareness >=  0.8){
                contours.remove(i);
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
            Imgproc.drawContours(capturedFrame, contours, i, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
        }

        showImg.show(capturedFrame);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("remove.png", capturedFrame);

    }
```

Here is the original image:

[image]

Here is the image before any contours are removed:

[image]

Here is the image final image where contours some contours should be removed:

[image]

Comment: The first thing I see it when you remove contour, you need to decrease counter i .

Comment: Is there anything else I should do? @AndreySmorodov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`squareness <= 0.7 && squareness >=  0.8` Looks like impossibe condition do you `mean squareness <= 0.7 || squareness >=  0.8` ?

Comment: I mean that squareness is  greater than 0.7 and less than 0.8

Comment: How it may be simultaneously less than lo bound and larger than up bound ? Try to plot interval on paper and put point there. May be squareness >= 0.7 && squareness <=  0.8 ?

Comment: I just want to remove values that aren't in between 0.7 and 0.8

Comment: Ok, then not squareness <= 0.7 && squareness >=  0.8 but squareness <= 0.7 || squareness >= 0.8 .

Comment: alright so if I was to add contours between 0.7 and 0.8 would it be what i posted?

Comment: Yes, the condition for remove talks "remove all contours for which squareness <= 0.7 or squareness >= 0.8, and don't touch  squareness >= 0.7 and squareness <= 0.8.